# Any way to get a response back from Google when hd key values are not matching with the attempted emails domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-oauth

I am building an application, where I want to onboard users using google authentication/authorization. I have some whitelisted domains, only users belonging to that domain should be able to signup/signin. I found [`hd`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) param to do this. When I am using `hd` key with a list of domains, it is allowing users to login as usual whose email domain falls in the wihitelisted domains. Till now it is ok. But when I am testing with some emails whose domains are not whitelisted, google preventing the user to move to the next password page. But this way, I am not able to let the user know which domains we support and which are not. Is there anyway, google sends the a response back to the client/application when someone is trying to use the email which is domain not matching with any of the domains given with `hd` keys. If I can get this hints/response back from Google, I will be able to let the user know. But nothing such I am seeing in Google Oauth2.0 doc.

I got one answer/idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860648/in-rails-is-it-possible-to-limit-who-can-log-in-with-google-using-the-api), but it is not convincing me.